# Constructing a nonabelian group of order 36

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First I show $G$ has a normal subgroup.

Let $n_3=|\operatorname{Syl}_3(G)|$. Then $n_3 \cong 1$ mod $3$. So $n_3=1$ or $n_3=4$. If $n_3=1$ then we are done. If $n_3=4$ then $G$ acts on $\operatorname{Sylow}_3(G)$ by conjugation and induces a homomorphism $G \rightarrow S_4$. It is plain to see that this can not be an embedding of $G$ and so the the induced homomorphism has a nontrivial kernel, and thus $G$ has a normal subgroup.

How can I use this normal subgroup to form a semi-direct product and thus show  $G$ is nonabelian? Or will this not work because I don't have the explicit normal subgroup?

My original question was try to find a group $G$ of order $p^2q^2$ with $p<q$ and $p$ divides $q^2-1$ such that $G$ is nonabelian.

Comment: Consider semidirect products or groups such as $D_6 \times C_3$

Comment: I think the question might be looking for a construction in the general case rather than a specific example??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in the title has simple answers, such as $S_3 \times S_3$ and $C_6 \times S_3$.

Comment: There are $10$ non-abelian groups of order $36$. It would be nice to provide them, for completeness.

Comment: For a classification, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1713435/589 and https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_36.

Answer (score 4):

How about the dihedral group of order $36$? I am not sure why this hasn't been mentioned yet.